# How can I apply converting within my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have seen this resolved on here different time however I'm unsure how to apply this conversion in this case. Please see error messages and code below:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
>
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_Loans_to_Date 
    @ReportDate DATETIME   
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DayofWeek VARCHAR(100),
            @BeginofWeek DATE,
            @BeginofMonth DATE,
            @BeginofYear DATE

    SET @DayofWeek = DATENAME(DW, @ReportDate)
    SET @BeginofWeek = (SELECT 
                            CASE 
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Sunday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, 0, @ReportDate)
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Monday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, -1, @ReportDate)
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Tuesday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, -2, @ReportDate)
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Wednesday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, -3, @ReportDate)
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Thursday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, -4, @ReportDate)
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Friday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, -5, @ReportDate)
                               WHEN @DayofWeek = 'Saturday' 
                                  THEN DATEADD(DD, -6, @ReportDate) 
                            END BeginofWeek)
    SET @BeginofMonth = (SELECT 
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(MM, @ReportDate)) + '1'+ 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(YY, @ReportDate))))
    SET @BeginofYear =  (SELECT ('1/1' + 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(YY, @ReportDate))))

    SELECT 
        SSN, LoanDate,
        CASE
           WHEN LoanDate >= @BeginofWeek AND LoanDate <= @ReportDate 
              THEN 'WeektoDate'
           WHEN LoanDate >= @BeginofWeek AND LoanDate <= @ReportDate 
              THEN 'MonthtoDate'
           WHEN LoanDate >= @BeginofWeek AND LoanDate <= @ReportDate 
              THEN 'YeartoDate' 
           ELSE NULL 
        END ToDate,
        CASE
           WHEN LoanDate >= @BeginofWeek AND  LoanDate <= @ReportDate 
              THEN 1
           WHEN LoanDate >= @BeginofWeek AND  LoanDate <= @ReportDate 
              THEN 2
           WHEN LoanDate >= @BeginofWeek AND  LoanDate <= @ReportDate 
              THEN 3 
           ELSE NULL 
        END ToDateOrder
    FROM
        [dbo].[Dim_Loan];

END
```

Comment: 1> If you could provide DDL and sample data it would be easier to provide a proper solution, 2> You might want to edit your code, I see some unintentional issue in terms of your comparison for MonthToDate and YearToDate where you are comparing with @BeginofWeek, 3> The first date of each category can much easily be calculated with use of DATEDIFF and DATEADD without complicating them.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to avoid unnecessary date->string->date conversions, you can get those values in this simpler way

```
DECLARE @DayofWeek INT,
        @BeginofWeek DATE,
        @BeginofMonth DATE,
        @BeginofYear DATE

SET @DayofWeek = DATEPART(DW, @ReportDate)
SET @BeginofWeek = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - @DayofWeek, @ReportDate)
SET @BeginofMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@ReportDate), MONTH(@ReportDate), 1)
SET @BeginofYear = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@ReportDate), 1, 1)
```

Comment: LifeSaver! thank you so much! - will remember  that moving forward - was trying to complicate things too much